# How much accuracy does PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY give?

Tags: android, gps, location

I'd like to receive location updates with a certain accuracy for tracking motorcycle riders in a city, which means that an accuracy range of approximatelly 50m to 200m would be reasonable. How do I map this to the setPriority() parameter ? In other words, given current location services implementation and some set of devices (define them ?) does this map to PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY or to PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For 50m- 200m accuray you need GPS all the time.
There is no half power GPS, none of other locationg technics achieve this accuracy.
(Cell Tower 1000m, and Wlan spots 50m if you have one, but often there is none.)

If the app has to track them, you have to use GPS_PROVIDER